# Access functions from required files within required files

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

In my app.js, I require the following two files:

```
var Util = require('./app_modules/Util.js');
var User = require('./app_modules/User.js');
```

User has this function:

```
this.showIP = function() {
  console.log(Util.getIP());
}
```

By calling it from app.js, I get the error:
Util is not defined.

I want to make Util global, but it should only be global for the current socket. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you require `Util.js` inside `User.js`?

Comment: No.. is this common practice?

Comment: The problem is, that I don't want several instances of the prototypes. When i set User.name in Util.js, it should be set for the other file, too..

Comment: Ok, but to set `User.name` inside `Util.js`, you have to require `User.js` there, right? Otherwise you'll run into the same problem.